# Setting only the ID in a Linq to SQL object

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL in a two tier project where the server tier abstracts the DB and is using Linq to SQL.
In my client tier I construct an object and I send to the server.

I have a Task, which has a relationship to Reporter (who reported this task), so Task has a ReportedID column in the database, which is a FK to Reporter.ID.

In the Linq abstraction, my Task has a Reporter property and a ReportedID property.

To save new Tasks, I would like to use the ReportedID, so I have this code:

```
//Populate the object with the info
        Task task = new Task();
        task.Title = tbTitle.Text;
        task.Description = tbDescription.Text;
        task.Severity = ((Severity)lbSeverities.SelectedItem);
        //the first state: "open"
        task.StateID = 1;

        //TODO - Set ReporterID
        task.ReporterID = 1;


        //Save the task
        client.SaveTaskCompleted += new EventHandler<SaveTaskCompletedEventArgs>(client_SaveTaskCompleted);
        client.SaveTaskAsync(App.Token, task);
```

So, the object is constructed and sent to the server, where it is saved using this code:

```
public Task SaveTask(string token, Task task)
    {
        TrackingDataContext dataConext = new TrackingDataContext();

        //Saves/Updates the task
        dataConext.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(task);
        dataConext.SubmitChanges();

        return task;
    }
```

The problem is that I get an exception: "An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a Reporter and a Task. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (Task.ReporterID) cannot be set to null.".
If I use the Reporter property, it works.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some refactory in my code and this error doesn't anymore. It may be a logic error but I can't tell exactly what.